# The Tethys Salinity Crisis

Tags: science-based, geography, sea, prehistoric-times

From 5.96 to 5.33 million years ago, disaster struck the Mediterranean Sea.  A tectonic snag turned this...

[image: Image of modern Mediterranean Sea]

...into something like this.

[image: Image of Mediterranean Sea drastically dried up, with the Iberian peninsula fused with Africa, the Tyrrhenian Sea is dry, and the Suez canal is land.]

In this alternate scenario, the sea separating modern Europe from modern Africa isn't the Mediterranean, but one of our old friends, the Tethys.

[image: Image of the Mediterranean swollen with Turkey and Iran underwater, connecting the Persian Gulf with the Mediterranean.]

As you can see, unlike the more shut-door Mediterranean, the Tethys has two openings--the Atlantic on one side and the Indian on another.  Assume that the Tethys had its own salinity crisis in its geological history.  With connections to both the Atlantic and the Indian, would the extent of evaporation and dehydration be as bad as back home?  Better?  Or worse?

Comment: How is this broad?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. To me, this question actually looks fairly reasonable and well-constrained (answer options are literally "better/worse/same"). Unfortunately it's above my pay grade in geography to be able to answer myself (that ain't sayin' much!).

Comment: I don't understand how the Tethys sea would dry out with such a large connection to the Indian ocean. Gibralter is (relatively) easy to close because it only a few miles wide, and there are high mountains on either side. In your proposed Tethys, you have submerged the entirety of the Anatolian and Zagros mountain chains. Given that, where is the high land that could potentially close off the Tethys from the Indian ocean? I don't see how this Tethys could have a salinity crisis.

Comment: I don't think your map is plausible. Iraq is low-lying, it should flood before practically any of Iran. The Caspian, likewise, should double in size to the North long before more than a corner of Iran is underwater. And even if the water level rose until most of Iran was flooded, it still won't connect the Mediterranean to the Indian Ocean unless you can cover the Zagros Mountains in a few *miles* of water, which would flood Egypt, Libya, and the Arabian Peninsula at the least.

Comment: @Charles  This is a map of an ALTERNATE Earth.

Comment: @JohnWDailey In that case I think we need to know more about the geography of your alternate earth.

Comment: @Charles  http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3950/great-lakes-earth-series

Comment: @JohnWDailey That explains the motivation behind the question, but not the relevant geographic details. If alternate-Turkey and alternate-Iran have a sea floor similar in depth to the rest of our world's Mediterranean, then there's no salinity crisis at all: you would have huge, slow-moving inflows from the Indian Ocean. If it's shallow, you might have seasonal inflow and outflow that brings in a significant amount of salt and doesn't remove much.

Answer (score 3):

**Unlikely without an Ice Age**

Assuming the same evaporation deficit that exists today existed then, you still won't have a serious drop in water levels unless all connections to the seas are sealed off.

An ice age would dramatically reduce sea levels, causing proto-Gilbraltar to block at the west, and perhaps expose the shallowest areas of the eastern connection.  Glaciation might also help stop the basin from recharging from the east, for part of the year.

If evaporation caused the same severe heat as was posited for the recent (6 million years ago) crisis, the Tethyian Crisis might be self-mitigating, boosting temperatures and sea levels, thus accelerating its own recovery.